# the set of all matrices which represent orthogonal projection in $M_n(C)$ is closed

Tags: general-topology

The set of all matrices which represent orthogonal projection in $M_n(C)$ is closed. I can not identify the set. Can you please help me to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set you are looking for is the following:
$$\mathrm{Gr}_n(\mathbb{C}):=\{A\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})\textrm{ s.t. } A^2=A,{}^\intercal\overline{A}=A\}.$$
It is closed, since it is given as an intersection of closed sets. Indeed, the two following maps $A\mapsto A^2-A$ and $A\mapsto{}^\intercal{\overline{A}}-A$ are continuous (why?).

**Remark.** Being a projector is exactly asking $A^2=A$ and orthogonality reads as ${}^\intercal\overline{A}A=I_n$.

---

If you are wondering why I called this set $\textrm{Gr}_n(\mathbb{C})$ it is because one has:
$$\textrm{Gr}_n(\mathbb{C})=\coprod_{k=0}^n\textrm{Gr}_{n,k}(\mathbb{C}),$$
where [$\textrm{Gr}_{n,k}(\mathbb{C})$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian) is the collection of $k$-planes in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: You meant the set of all Hermitian , Idempotent Matrices..@C.Falcon

Comment: Idempotent matrices correspond to projectors and an idempotent matrix is unitary if and only if it is Hermitian. By the way, I assumed that by orthogonality you meant unitary as we work over $\mathbb{C}$, if not remove the conjugation.

Comment: I did not get you . Can you please elaborate why the set is not the set of all Hermitian , Idempotent Matrices?

Comment: In the end, it is. What is your question regarding my answer, exactly?

Comment: Your Answer is fine to me. But Can I call $Gr_n(c)$ as the  set of all matrices which are idempotent and orthogonal?

Comment: Oh, sure! It can be whatever you like, I was just giving an already existing notation to this set as explained in my appendix.